# Rails, Omniauth, Authlogic, and Facebook - first step

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, authlogic, omniauth

I'm trying to get Facebook logins working on my app using Rails, Authlogic, and Omniauth. I'm following the first steps of http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1 as precisely as possible.

I have:

- added the `omniauth` gem, run `bundle install`.
- created a new Authentication nifty-scaffold with fields `user_id`, `provider`, and `uid`.
- added the route: `match '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'authentications#create'`
- added to config/initializers/omniauth.rb:

  ```
  Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :facebook, '20...my_app_id', 'bc...my_app_secret'
  end
  ```

The server then fails to restart:

```
/Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:206:
    in 'const_missing_from_s3_library': uninitialized constant 
    OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook (NameError)
    from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/ext/module.rb:36:in 'const_missing'
    from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/omniauth-1.0.0/lib/omniauth/builder.rb:22:in 'const_get'
    from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/omniauth-1.0.0/lib/omniauth/builder.rb:22:in 'provider'
    from /Users/san/Documents/sanj/myapp/config/initializers/omniauth.rb:2:in 'block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in 'instance_eval'
    from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in 'initialize'
    from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/omniauth-1.0.0/lib/omniauth/builder.rb:7:in 'initialize'
    from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:33:in 'new'
    from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:33:in 'build'
    from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:79:in 'block in build'
    from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:79:in 'each'
    from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:79:in 'inject'
    from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:79:in 'build'
    from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/application.rb:162:in 'app'
    from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:35:in 'block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in 'instance_exec'
    from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in 'run'
    from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in 'block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in 'each'
    from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in 'run_initializers'
    from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in 'initialize!'
    from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in 'method_missing'
    from /Users/san/Documents/sanj/myapp/config/environment.rb:5:in '<top (required)>'
    from /Users/san/Documents/sanj/myapp/config.ru:3:in 'block in <main>'
    from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in 'instance_eval'
    from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in 'initialize'
    from /Users/san/Documents/sanj/myapp/config.ru:1:in 'new'
    from /Users/san/Documents/sanj/myapp/config.ru:1:in '<main>'
    from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:35:in 'eval'
    from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:35:in 'parse_file'
    from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:162:in 'app'
    from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:253:in 'wrapped_app'
    from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:204:in 'start'
    from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:65:in 'start'
    from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:30:in 'block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in 'tap'
    from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in '<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:7:in 'require'
    from script/rails:7:in '<main>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The omniauth gem was just bumped to version 1.0 as of yesterday (http://intridea.com/2011/11/2/omniauth-1-0), and there are some changes to how the gem is used that are not covered in the railscast.

I found my solution on this page: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/OmniAuth-1.0

The biggest different is that each strategy is now contained within its own gem, so for facebook, you would change the line in your gem file that currently reads "gem 'omniauth'" to "gem 'omniauth-facebook'".

I didn't have to change any other code, and you may have to run "bundle update" to get everything to click through.

Answer (score 5):

I had to do 'require "omniauth"' or 'require "omniauth-facebook"' in my config/development.rb file.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem and this is what was wrong with me:

You can't have your facebook oauth gem in the Development list in your gem file. Heroku only reads the Production ones, so move it up out of the Development list.